# Installing Active directory or Ldap server in windows container

Tags: docker, active-directory, ldap, containers

I'd like to test a product using Docker windows containers.
I need a container with Active directory or Ldap server.
Does anyone know how to accomplish that?
Thanks

Comment: Do you want a container with windows inside or do you want to run a container on the windows host? @ldanG.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear about whether you want the container to run on windows host or you want windows to run inside the container in which you want LDAP.

Regarding former, you can start OpenLDAP by following commands in a windows host machine with docker for-windows installed:

```
docker pull osixia/openldap
docker run --name my-openldap-container --detach osixia/openldap
```

The details on how to configure the OpenLDAP container is given here:

https://github.com/osixia/docker-openldap